# (R)How to add importFrom for grid.newpage()?

Tags: r, roxygen2

My goal is to convert R code to package. And the code contain grid.newpage() like this as below. How to add importFrom comment? Because when I tried "#' importFrom grid newpage", package doesn't show graph.(Maybe the newpage() is not actually from grid?)

```
showTest <-function() {
  library(grid)
  grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 1)))
     print(plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi), vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1 ,layout.pos.col=1))      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is called `grid`, and the function is called `grid.newpage` so the form you need is

```
#' importFrom grid grid.newpage
```